# How can search whole word only and should not exist?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

```
dir C:\dev\ve1 -Include *.scala -Recurse |
  Select-String -Pattern "ValidSite" -SimpleMatch -CaseSensitive
```

This is working fine but I want lines which have **whole word only** but it giving `ValidSiteId`.

And the line **should contain 'ValidSite' and should not contain 'case' word**.

I gone through all the options of `Select-String` and I tried multiple ways but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Match on word boundaries (`\b`) and pipe the result through another `Select-String` with your negative condition:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\dev\ve1 -Include *.scala -Recurse |
  Select-String -Pattern "\bValidSite\b" -CaseSensitive |
  Select-String -Pattern "\bCase\b" -NotMatch -CaseSensitive
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look to a regular expression :

```
dir C:\dev\ve1 -Include *.scala -Recurse | Select-String '^(?!.*case).*ValidSite .*$'
```

`^. ... *ValidSite .*$` should be clear enough. The first part, `(?!.*case)` is a negative look-ahead: before matching the string it checks the string does not contain "case" (with any number of characters before it).